# FIRCLSReportManager error on Firebase iOS SDK

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm getting this error everytime my app starts :

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]
PID: 5264, TID: 1948690, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x107c31d80 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   app                         0x0000000104debcf4 -[FIRCLSReportManager captureInitialNotificationStates] + 144
5   app                         0x0000000104deba88 -[FIRCLSReportManager setupStateNotifications] + 44
6   app                         0x0000000104de9478 -[FIRCLSReportManager startCrashReporterWithProfilingMark:report:] + 256
7   app                         0x0000000104de8210 -[FIRCLSReportManager startWithProfilingMark:] + 1188
8   app                         0x0000000104e01be4 -[FIRCrashlytics initWithApp:appInfo:installations:analytics:] + 1448
9   app                         0x0000000104e022e8 __38+[FIRCrashlytics componentsToRegister]_block_invoke + 532

10  app                         0x0000000104daf8bc -[FIRComponentContainer instantiateInstanceForProtocol:withBlock:] + 132
11  app                         0x0000000104dafb60 -[FIRComponentContainer instanceForProtocol:] + 344
12  app                         0x0000000104db0234 +[FIRComponentType instanceForProtocol:inContainer:] + 104
13  app                         0x0000000104e023d8 +[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] + 136
14  app                         0x0000000104923488 -[CrashReportingManager logWithFormat:arguments:] + 136
15  app                         0x00000001049233e8 -[CrashReportingManager logWithFormat:] + 84
16  app                         0x00000001049d6e4c __49-[AccountManager clearTempDataStorageCompletion:]_block_invoke + 636
17  Foundation                          0x00000001b04a33a0 7B1733B1-74C9-3A33-8A58-853B0A029826 + 1131424
18  Foundation                          0x00000001b03ad0c8 7B1733B1-74C9-3A33-8A58-853B0A029826 + 123080
19  Foundation                          0x00000001b04a5628 7B1733B1-74C9-3A33-8A58-853B0A029826 + 1140264
20  Foundation                          0x00000001b03acd60 7B1733B1-74C9-3A33-8A58-853B0A029826 + 122208
21  Foundation                          0x00000001b04a6020 7B1733B1-74C9-3A33-8A58-853B0A029826 + 1142816
22  Foundation                          0x00000001b04a5aec 7B1733B1-74C9-3A33-8A58-853B0A029826 + 1141484
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107a8d268 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107a7ebd8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107a817dc _dispatch_continuation_pop + 524
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107a80c5c _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 624
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107a90160 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107a90a88 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001afdfab48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001afdfd760 start_wqthread + 8
```

It seems Firebase is calling `statusBarOrientation` on a background thread ?

Is anyone else getting this or knows how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `+[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics]` on a non-main thread.

Comment: Actually, accessing [FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] on a non-main thread is permitted. But you gave me the right direction: it looks like [FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] cannot be called _the first time_ on a background thread.